# Luxon.js get the count of days in each month for a given date range

Tags: luxon

Is there is an efficient way to get a count of days grouped by month in a date range?

For example, given a date range of 2020-01-30 to 2020-02-03 the output would be `{ 'January': 2, 'February': 3 }`.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no more efficient way other than calculating it.

```js
const firstDateToPass = { year: 2020, month: 1, day: 26 };
const secondDateToPass = { year: 2020, month: 1, day: 29 };

const getCountOfDaysGroupedByMonth = (startDate, endDate) => {
  const firstMonthDateTime = DateTime.fromObject(startDate);
  const secondMonthDateTime = DateTime.fromObject(endDate);
  if (firstMonthDateTime.month === secondMonthDateTime.month) {
    // In same month
    // Return difference in days
    return {
      [firstMonthDateTime.monthLong]: secondMonthDateTime.day - firstMonthDateTime.day
    }
  }
}

console.log(getCountOfDaysGroupedByMonth(firstDateToPass, secondDateToPass)) // { January: 3 }
```

You just need to cover the cases when it spans over multiple months, but I'll leave that figuring out to you for now?